# The requested URL did not return Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, partial-views

Here is my grid which is in MyPartialView:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyClass>()
        .Name("GridMyClass")
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage))
            .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(a => a.Id))
                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnError("Grid_onError"))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Timestamp).Width(110).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage);
                commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage);
            }).Width(180).Title("Edit");
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("Ge", "MyClass")
            .Update("Edit", "MyClass")
            .Delete("Delete", "MyClass")
            .Insert("Insert", "MyClass");
        })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    //.Scrollable()
    //.Groupable()
    //.Filterable()
    //.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

)

Here is one of the controller methods (the others are similar):

```
public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        //delete

        //get the model

        List<MyClassTemplate> ct = new List<MyClassTemplate>();
        //fill ct
        return PartialView("MyPartialView", new GridModel<MyClassTemplate> { Data = ct });
    }
```

And another controller method:

```
public ActionResult MyPartialView()
    {
        List<MyClassTemplate> ct = new List<MyClassTemplate>();
        //fill ct 
        return PartialView(ct);//new GridModel(ct)
    }
```

When I edit a row in the grid and click on the image to save the edited row, I step with breakpoints throught the controller methods. Everything is fine. ct has ok value. However, I get alert "Error! The requested URL did not return Json.". Which url did not return json? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was pretty self-explanatory. Instead of a partial view, I should have returned json.